# Unabel to ping or ssh from a client to other client in openvpn

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Network Engineering Stack Exchange post: [Unabel to ping or ssh from a client to other client in openvpn](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/59788/unabel-to-ping-or-ssh-from-a-client-to-other-client-in-openvpn)

Set up an OpenVPN server on VPS(S) I was in need to ssh to office laptop from home laptop now 3 devices connected to VPN, office ubuntu 16.04 laptop(A), home ubuntu 18.04 laptop(B), android phone(C). I can ping and ssh connect to (C) The problem is I can't ping or SSH connect to (A) or (B). even (S) couldn't ping (A) or (B).

Answer (score 3):

The Meta stack exchange is intended for questions about this Stack Exchange, not for asking questions about networking.

Your question was closed because it is off topic here. As hinted in the comments, you can consider asking this question on https://www.serverfault.com.